# Is it possible to define functions for a type, and then compile it to an isomorphic representation of it?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, coq, agda, idris

Suppose that I define the following type for hexadecimal strings:

```
data HexDigit
  = H0 | H1 | H2 | H3
  | H4 | H5 | H6 | H7
  | H8 | H9 | HA | HB
  | HC | HD | HE | HF

Hex : Type
Hex = List HexDigit
```

This type is very simple, but probably inefficient when compiled to the JS backend. Another way to represent hexadecimal strings would be to use a subset of the native `string` type:

```
data IsNib : Char -> Type where
  IsNib0 : IsNib '0'
  IsNib1 : IsNib '1'
  IsNib2 : IsNib '2'
  IsNib3 : IsNib '3'
  IsNib4 : IsNib '4'
  IsNib5 : IsNib '5'
  IsNib6 : IsNib '6'
  IsNib7 : IsNib '7'
  IsNib8 : IsNib '8'
  IsNib9 : IsNib '9'
  IsNibA : IsNib 'a'
  IsNibB : IsNib 'b'
  IsNibC : IsNib 'c'
  IsNibD : IsNib 'd'
  IsNibE : IsNib 'e'
  IsNibF : IsNib 'f'

data IsHex : String -> Type where
  IsHexNil : IsHex "0x"
  IsHexApp : IsHex s -> IsNib c0 -> IsNib c1 -> IsHex (s ++ singleton c0 ++ singleton c1)

Hex : Type
Hex = (s : String ** IsHex)
```

This would probably be more efficient, but I'm having [a lot of issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48123439/how-to-prove-that-a-string-is-in-hexadecimal-format) working with that type (possibly due to not having enough experience on Idris yet).

**Is it possible to build a library based on the first definition of `Hex`, but then, after compiling it to a backend, actually use the second definition, given that they're clearly isomorphic?**

Comment: Your 2nd type is difficult to work with because it is quite a silly encoding. How about `data IsNib : Char -> Type where IsNib : '0' <= c -> c <= 'f' -> IsNib c` with some suitable encoding of `<=`?

Comment: Have you checked that your second encoding is more efficient?  I don't know what kinds of optimizations idris does, but without optimizations the proof term for `IsHex` is almost the same as your first encoding (to see this, ignore its type parameter), and then you *tuple* it with a string that contains the same information

Comment: If you want an efficient representation, use an efficient representation (like an [unboxed vector](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.1/docs/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html)).

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Idris has unboxed vectors?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, one answer is to rewrite the constructors as constant identifiers: `H0 = IsNib '0'`, etc.

In this case, adding `deriving Enum` to your first definition would allow the default `toEnum` and `fromEnum` to convert between your first encoding and numbers from 0 to 15.  You can then convert those using your library of choice (such as bit-shifts and bitwise and from `Data.Bits` or `intHex` from `Data.ByteString.Builder`).  You could also derive an instance of `Show` to convert hex digits to a one-`Char` `String` and `concat` them.